# LaTeX does not work in comments?

Tags: discussion, formatting, mathjax

I think that LaTeX doesn't work on comments. I have made a few tests and I don't see it happening. LaTeX works fine on answers and questions, so I don't think it is a problem with my browser.

So, two questions:

1) Is LaTeX disabled on comments?

2) If it is disabled, why? I think it is inconsistent. This site can potentially include lots of mathematics.

Comment: I've definitely used it before...or maybe I dreamt it.

Comment: @blochwave Maybe it's a problem with my browser. Can anyone report on a recent LaTeX comment?

Comment: From [editing-help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting): "Comments support only bold, italic, code and links".

Comment: Actually that information is incorrect. It is possible, just surround your expression with dollar signs. [Proof](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59979/held-keys-in-associations#comment217765_80388). It is just not possible on meta. Here is the same string: Test: $\alpha$. Sorry system

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I see the $\alpha$ on the main site. Apparently it was a temporary issue with my browser and/or proxy or whatever. Thanks. If you post an answer (a simple "No, comments are not disabled on the main site" will do) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, comments with LaTeX are not disabled on the main site, see my comment above.